# Can rough paint texture on a ceiling be touched up?

Tags: ceiling, painting, flashing

I'm redecorating a room and having some issues with the ceiling and light.

After sanding the walls and ceiling, I painted the ceiling with Zinsser Perma-White Matt as I heard it was good. Unfortunately my trusty roller frame let me down and kept slipping the paint around and not rolling particularly well. Stupidly, it took me 2 coats of paint to realise that the bearings were jammed with dried paint from other jobs! I had to do a third coat with a new roller frame to even out the paint as it looked so poor.

Just inspecting the work today, looks pretty good in most areas apart from one spot...

Fine here

[image]

Not so good here

[image]

I think I tried to spread the paint too thin in this area, although correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is: can I "touch up" this area using the same roller and paint? if so, how?
I don't mind doing another coat of paint but I'm aware that the more coats I do the more of a stipple effect will show on the ceiling. I went the extra effort to sand the whole thing down to reduce this as much as possible and at this rate it's starting to feel pointless!

I painted it using a 9 inch roller, but I have a 4 inch roller and frame of the same brand if that helps (wooster)

Comment: You can repeat a sand/repaint (foam roller for lower stipple?) in some paint suitable for overpainting the zinsser.. and if it's water soluble, smoothing out with a damp sponge after it has dried can further reduce stipple.. Or just leave it; people never look up - my joker brother drew a some cartoon genitalia on my kitchen ceiling some number of years ago and to date no guest has ever noticed.. You only notice because you look for it (whether you can let that go is probably a psychology question for another site?)

Comment: @CaiusJard, answers go down there. Also, your guests may be trying not to embarrass you (or themselves). Your logic is flawed.

Comment: If I'd intended it to be an answer, it would have been posted as one

Comment: if the spots are very noticeable, you might try to feather them in with a spray primer before the next coat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can re-roll that area. Just [use plenty of paint](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/125904/35141) and blend it outward in a radial pattern so you aren't left with hard edges. Matte finish paint is quite forgiving, which is why we use it on ceilings.

I wouldn't sand it. Sanding latex paint can make things worse by tearing up the surface too much. ;

Comment: I agree especially on new work it is fairly easy to blend in that bare spot, starting heavy and working out like Isherwood stated.